# Upgrade to Spring Boot 2.4 causes GrantedAuthoritiesMapper to stop working with OAuth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to [upgrade JHipster to use Spring Boot 2.4](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/13551). The app I'm testing has a Spring Security Configuration that enables OAuth Login and sets up a resource server with Spring Security:

```java
        .and()
            .oauth2Login()
        .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter())
                .and()
            .and()
                .oauth2Client();
```

After upgrading to Spring Boot 2.4, my `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` bean is no longer invoked, so my authorities are no longer translated. Any idea why?

```java
    /**
     * Map authorities from "groups" or "roles" claim in ID Token.
     *
     * @return a {@link GrantedAuthoritiesMapper} that maps groups from
     * the IdP to Spring Security Authorities.
     */
    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return authorities -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(
                authority -> {
                    // Check for OidcUserAuthority because Spring Security 5.2 returns
                    // each scope as a GrantedAuthority, which we don't care about.
                    if (authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority) {
                        OidcUserAuthority oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) authority;
                        mappedAuthorities.addAll(SecurityUtils.extractAuthorityFromClaims(oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo().getClaims()));
                    }
                }
            );
            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Spring Security 5.4.0 [removed the default scopes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8514), so I had to add the following property:

```
scope: openid,profile,email
```

See [this commit](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/13551/commits/188e79a01d8523abfa62f1232bec9341bc8fa075) for more info.